# How can I monitor life of threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to know if there's a way to monitor the life of a thread but I'll explain the context of what I'm doing so maybe there's a better way to do this.

Basically I have x threads that are working on a queue and processing it, if a thread gets a acceptable result it goes into a solutions queue otherwise the data is either discarded or further processed.

My problem is in my main thread I have a like `while(!solutions_results.isEmpty())` and it saves the data(right now its print to a file but later maybe database).  The obvious problem is once it clears the solutions queue its done and finishes working even though the other threads are still putting data into the queue.

I'm not sure the best way to deal with this(maybe have a dedicated thread that only saves the solution queue?) but I was thinking if I could somehow monitor the life of the other threads are done then there's no chance of more data going into the solutions queue.

if there's a better way to do this please let me know otherwise is there a way to tell once the other threads are done(I can't wait for executor to completely finish before running this process because it can get quite large and don't want it to just sit in memory, ideally want to process it as it close to as it comes in but its not time dependent)?

Comment: This is the [Producer Consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem). Maybe that article will give you some insight.

Comment: @jpm Thank you so much, I'll read it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `ExecutorService` to run your thread jobs then you can use the `awaitTermination()` method to know when all of the threads have finished:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
pool.submit(yourSolutionsRunnable);
pool.submit(yourSolutionsRunnable);
...
// once you've submitted your last job you can do
pool.shutdown();
```

Then you can wait for all of the jobs submitted to finish:

```
pool.waitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This would get more complicated if your threads need to keep running after submitting their solutions.  If you edit your question and make this more apparent I'll edit my answer.

---

**Edit:**

Oh, I see you want to process some results along the way but not stop until all of the threads are done.

You can use the `pool.isTerminated()` test which will tell you if all of the jobs have completed.  So your loop would look something like:

```
// this is the main thread so waiting for solutions in a while(true) loop is ok
while (true) {
    // are all the workers done?
    if (pool.isTerminated()) {
       // if there are results process one last time
       if (!solutions_results.isEmpty()) {
           processTheSolutions();
       }
       break;
    } else {
        if (solutions_results.isEmpty()) {
            // wait a bit to not spin, you could also use a wait/notify here
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } else {
            processTheSolutions();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

You could also have two thread pools, one for generating the solutions and another one processing.  Your main thread could then wait for the worker pool to empty and then wait for the solutions processing pool.  The worker pool would submit the solutions (if any) into the solutions pool.  You could just have 1 thread in the solutions processing pool or more as necessary.

```
ExecutorService workerPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
final ExecutorService solutionsPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
solutionsPool.submit(workerThatPutsSolutionsIntoSolutionsPool);
...
// once you've submitted your last worker you can do
workerPool.shutdown();

workerPool.waitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
// once the workers have finished you shutdown the solutions pool
solutionsPool.shutdown();
// and then wait for it to finish
solutionsPool.waitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: but will that prevent my processing of the solutions queue to wait until all threads are done? Is there a way to keep the solution queue running while the threads are alive so I can wrap it in a while loop?

Comment: gray your right, the threads are still executing.  There's two queues one is a work queue and one is a solutions queue. As long as the work queue is not empty I have a fixed number of threads processing it.

Comment: Thank you so much Gray. it worked! I did have to modify one part, `if (pool.isTerminated()) {` in your second edit will just cause it to exit if the dataset is small and threads finish while this process is sleeping.  I changed it to `if (executor.isTerminated() && solutions_results.isEmpty()) {` and it seems to work. I'll test more but thanks so much this is exactly what I was looking for. Have a great weekend.

Comment: Right @learningJava.  I tweaked my loop for posterity.  Glad it worked.

Comment: @learningJava this actually looks like a good place to use `Future` and `Callable`. Really, an `ExecutorCompletionService` is what you are after. But the answer given probably meets your current needs in a fairly simplistic way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the behavior requirements that you're dealing with but if you want the main thread to block until all your child threads are complete you should take a look at the `join` method of the `Thread` class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()

Just run a loop inside your main thread that calls the join method on each one of your child threads and when it exits the loop you can be sure that all threads have finished working.

Comment: but won't that make my program wait for all the processes to complete before starting?  The program runs for a very long time and I'd rather deal with it as it comes in.

Comment: No problem, I'm learning and new so 99% of the time I'm not explaining this right.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a list of your active threads.  You'd want it synchronized to keep it from being trashed if you add/remove threads simultaneously.  Or use something like java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue, which can deal with multiple threads itself.  Add each thread to the list when you start it.  Each thread should remove itself from the list right before it stops.  When the list is empty, all your threads are done.

**Edit:**  the timing is important.  **First,** the main thread has to put the working threads into the list.  If they put themselves into the list, the main thread could check the list at a time when some threads have removed themselves from the list and all the rest, though started, have not yet begun executing--and so not yet put themselves in the list.  It would then think everything was done when it wasn't.  **Second,** the main thread must put each worker thread on the list *before* it starts it.  Otherwise, the thread might finish and make its attempt to remove itself from the list *before* the main thread adds it to the list. Then the list will never become empty and the program will never finish.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService would be useful here.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class monitor_life_of_threads
{
    /**
     * First, convert all of your threads to instances of Callable (easy to do), and have them each return an instance some class (I'm using Integer below just as 
     * an example).
     * This will help simplify things.
     */

    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {
        final monitor_life_of_threads worker = new monitor_life_of_threads();

        worker.executeCallablesAndUseResults ();

        System.exit ( 0 );
    }

    private void executeCallablesAndUseResults ()
    {
        List < Callable < Result >> list = new ArrayList <> ();
        populateInputList ( list );

        try
        {
            doWork ( list );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch ( ExecutionException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch ( CancellationException e )
        {
            /*
             * Could be called if a Callable throws an InterruptedException, and if it's not caught, it can cause Future.get to hang.
             */
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch ( Exception defaultException )
        {
            defaultException.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

    private void doWork ( Collection < Callable < Result >> callables ) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool ();

        CompletionService < Result > ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService < > ( executorService );

        for ( Callable < Result > callable : callables )
            ecs.submit ( callable );

        for ( int i = 0, n = callables.size (); i < n; ++i )
        {
            Result r = ecs.take ().get ();
            if ( r != null )
                use ( r ); // This way you don't need a second queue.
        }

        executorService.shutdown ();

    }

    private void use ( Result result )
    {
        // Write result to database, output file, etc.

        System.out.println ( "result = " + result );
    }

    private List < Callable < Result >> populateInputList ( List < Callable < Result >> list )
    {
        list.add ( new Callable < Result > () {

            @Override
            public Result call () throws Exception
            {
                // Do some number crunching, then return a 5.
                return new Result ( 5 );
            }

        } );

        list.add ( new Callable < Result > () {

            @Override
            public Result call () throws Exception
            {
                // Do some number crunching, then return an 8.
                return new Result ( 8 );
            }

        } );

        list.add ( new Callable < Result > () {

            @Override
            public Result call () throws Exception
            {
                // Do some number crunching, but fail and so return null.
                return null;
            }

        } );

        return list;
    }
}

class Result
{
    private Integer i;

    Result ( Integer i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public String toString ()
    {
        return Integer.toString ( i );
    }
}
```